# Setting Up LDAP on Odoo with Docker

Tags: docker, ldap, odoo

I'm using Docker to install Odoo version 9 on my Linux Centos server.  I need to use LDAP so I downloaded the addon, Authentication via LDAP, and saved it to my server in the directory  /mnt/extra-addons/auth_ldap.   When I started the Odoo container in Docker I pointed a Docker volume at the addon directory.  Below is the command I used.

```
docker run -v /path/to/addons:/mnt/extra-addons/auth_ldap -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo
```

The instructions Say  "After installing this module, you need to configure the LDAP parameters in the Configuration tab of the Company details".  But I can't find the LDAP settings in the company configuration tab.

Where is the configuration tab or I'm I missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addon module is included in the apps list, but the filters just stop it from appearing. The following are the instructions for install the auth_ldap addon for Odoo Version 9.

- Click on Administrator / About/ Activate the developer mode
- Click Ok
- Go to Apps / Update Apps List / Update
- Afterward update finished then click on the x next to Apps in the search box.
- Type 'auth' then click enter
- Click on install in Authentication via LDAP
- After install finishes click Setting/ General Settings/ Configure
  your company data/ Configuration / Edit
- Then add LDAP parameters.